# Stop adding line breaks between @Inject annoations

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

In Android Studio 4.0 with the default Kotlin code style guide, it automatically adds line breaks between properties with @Inject annotations, like this

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var sessionStore: SessionStore

    @Inject
    lateinit var networkModel: NetworkModel

    @Inject
    lateinit var eventRecorder: EventRecorder
```

I just want to see this:

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var sessionStore: SessionStore
    @Inject
    lateinit var networkModel: NetworkModel
    @Inject
    lateinit var eventRecorder: EventRecorder
```

I've looked in Preferences -> Code Style -> Kotlin  under "wrapping and braces" and "blank lines" but I haven't found anything that changes this behavior.

Comment: What is the intention of doing that? You should ideally follow the default style guide provided by Android Studio.